# Alternative of CWinThread

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++, platform-independent

I am trying to convert a piece of code which is written in Windows to a platform agnostic version, and need some suggestions on how we can convert the CWinThread functions (and data members) to something which is capable of working on all platforms (Linux, Mac etc). Any suggestions welcome.

Comment: What exactly do you want to know? Threading is standardized as [`std::thread`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread), but that isn't aware of platform specifics such as windows and message queues for which `CWinThread` has members.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the size of your program you could work with `#ifdef` and just add pthreads for unix based systems, or have a look at multi-platform libraries such as [here](https://github.com/cfnptr/mpmt) or [here](https://github.com/GerHobbelt/pthread-win32).

Comment: Thanks, yeah I considered #ifdef. The thing is I might be needing to write a new Wrapper function for all these, so the libraries might help in this case.